# Ruby on Rails - Sidekiq not sending email, stay lock up in schedule tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have a contact form that send a email with the fields to a admin email. I'm using Sidekiq and Redis. When I send the form, the task stay lock up in sidekiq schedule task and is never sent.

Has anyone ever experienced this? I've already tried many things to try fix this, but without success. I configured something wrong?

```
# app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Facens Liga <no-reply@facens.br>"
  def create(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: "felipe.marcon@atua.ag", subject: "Contato Através do Site")

  end
end


# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-status'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/6', namespace: 'facenliga' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/6', namespace: 'facensliga' }
end

# config/sidekiq.yml
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
production:
  :concurrency: 25
staging:
  :concurrency: 15
development:
  :concurrency: 25
```

I hope that someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Likely because you aren't processing the `default` queue, only `mailers`.

Comment: @MikePerham even if I put `default` in queue, the email it is not sended. I updated `: queues` in my question. What more can be?

Comment: What does the Web UI queues page show?

Comment: The problem was on namespaces. They was different between server and client. I figured out this today earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your namespace.  Don't use namespaces, as I wrote in my blog last year.

> The redis-namespace gem allows you to share a Redis database among several applications by prefixing every key with a namespace but it's a terrible hack that no one should use. Redis already has a native solution if you want to share a Redis instance: databases. The default database is 0. Here's how to point Sidekiq to use database 1 instead:

https://www.mikeperham.com/2017/04/10/migrating-from-redis-namespace/

Comment: The problem was on namespaces. They was different between server and client. I figured out this today earlier. Now I'm using enviroment variables to set namespaces and not be different between server and client.

I'll read your post. Thanks!